# не()изучившим правил -- слитно или раздельно?

Tags: орфография

"Едущий дорогой, не зная пути, когда встретятся две дороги, сомневается – тот ли его путь или другой, то же и с неизучившим правил композитором." (цитата автора 17 в.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Корректно раздельное написание. С полными формами причастий отрицание "не" пишется раздельно, если при них имеются зависимые слова.

Comment: Большое спасибо!

Comment: Серж, надо закавычить или "обыталить"  "не", иначе можно в двух протипоположных смыслах понять (отрицание "не пишется" раздельно -> пишется слитно). :)

Comment: Ой, я и не заметил, что Вы то же самое написали, Александр, когда исправлял!

Comment: Да,спасибо! ...

Answer (score 3):

Такое причастие *даже без зависимого* слова имело бы **отдельное** от частицы написание: оно по смыслу не может выполнять функцию прилагательного (которое пишется слитно): не бывает у человека свойства "неизучивший", но он вполне может быть "необученным". Здесь проявляется сильная связь причастия с переходным глаголом, от которого оно образовано: отсутствующее зависимое слово всегда будет подразумеваться и следовать из контекста:

`Каждый из вас должен изучить технику безопасности. 
Не изучивший не будет` `допущен к прыжкам с моста.`

Для сравнения:

```
Необученные (=необученный персонал) у нас к работе 

не допускаются, поэтому сначала вас направят на курсы и обучат.
```